# How long will stored powder charges last?

Tags: concrete, nails

I finished a basement well over a decade ago, and had leftover concrete nails and powder charges for my powder actuated nail gun.

I'm going to be driving a few nails into concrete for a tack strip, are these old charges likely to be safe and have the same power as new, or do powder charges degrade over time?

They have been stored in an outbuilding, so while protected from rain and pests, have been exposed to wide temperature extremes and varying humidity.

Answer (score 1):

While their power may be degraded, using them is not likely to be dangerous. The barrel of the nail gun is what really contains the blast.

Answer (score 1):

Treat it like you would ammunition. If there's no corrosion, they're probably fine.
If you start using it and you get misfires, dispose of it.